# Right aligning columns given conditions in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to selectively right align certain columns by applying `justify-content-end` and `text-right` when they match certain conditions for each record such that the rendered version looks something like this:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-8>Stuff</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row justify-content-end text-right>
      <ion-col col-8>Stuff 2</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-8>Stuff 3</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row justify-content-end text-right>
      <ion-col col-8>Stuff 4</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

How can I put that in the code? Would I need to use `*ngIf` in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `*ngIf`, all you need is `ngClass` :

```
<ion-row [ngClass]="{'justify-content-end': true, 'text-right': false }">...</ion-row>

// OR : If both classes have same conditions

<ion-row [ngClass]="{'justify-content-end text-right' : true}">...</ion-row>
```

In place of `true / false` use your `conditions`

For more details please read : **[NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)**

---

For dynamic attribute use,

```
[attr.justify-content-end]='true/false'
```

Comment: This seems to add `justify-content-end` and `text-right` to classes, but I need them added to `<ion-row>` as properties such that it looks something like: `<ion-row justify-content-end text-right>`.

Comment: then use [attr.justify-content-end]='true/false'

Comment: This one is the winner! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

When True:

```
<ion-row justify-content-end text-right *ngIf="msg.mycondition">
  <ion-col col-8>Stuff 2</ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row *ngIf="!msg.mycondition">
  <ion-col col-8>Stuff 2</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: How would this work when each ion-row is: `<ion-row *ngFor="let msg of messages" [...]>Stuff</ion-row>`?

Comment: Vivek Doshi's `[attr.justify-content-end]='true/false'` comment did it, thank you for the input!